# Aggregating in local timezone in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, datetime, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am building application in mongodb and nodejs that will be used in Italy . Italy timezone is +02:00 . This means if any one saving some data at 01:am of 11 July then it will be saved as 11:00 pm of 10 July as mongo saves date in UTC.
We need to show date wise tx count. So I made group by query on date. But it shows that tx in previous day. What should be workaround for this.

```
> db.txs.insert({txid:"1",date : new Date("2015-07-11T01:00:00+02:00")})

> db.txs.insert({txid:"2",date : new Date("2015-07-11T05:00:00+02:00")})

> db.txs.insert({txid:"3",date : new Date("2015-07-10T21:00:00+02:00")})

> db.txs.find().pretty()

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55a0a55499c6740f3dfe14e4"),
        "txid" : "1",
        "date" : ISODate("2015-07-10T23:00:00Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55a0a55599c6740f3dfe14e5"),
        "txid" : "2",
        "date" : ISODate("2015-07-11T03:00:00Z")
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("55a0a55699c6740f3dfe14e6"),
        "txid" : "3",
        "date" : ISODate("2015-07-10T19:00:00Z")
}

> db.txs.aggregate([
     { $group:{
         _id: { 
             day:{$dayOfMonth:"$date"}, 
             month:{$month:"$date"},
             year:{$year:"$date"} 
         },
         count:{$sum:1}
     }}
  ])

  { "_id" : { "day" : 11, "month" : 7, "year" : 2015 }, "count" : 1 }
  { "_id" : { "day" : 10, "month" : 7, "year" : 2015 }, "count" : 2 }
```

It shows 2  txs in 10th of July and 1 in 11 July . But we need to show 2 txs for 11 july and 1 tx for 10 July.

It was actually 11 July in Italy when

```
db.txs.insert({txid:"1",date : new Date("2015-07-11T01:00:00+02:00")})
```

took place but mongo stored date as:

```
ISODate("2015-07-10T23:00:00Z")
```

Comment: So what if someone from "New Zealand" wanted to see the data submitted by someone in "Italy"? How should you have stored the time then? That is the very reason why UTC dates are used as they represent the same point in time to everyone. Convert to local time on your "client" and also do the same with "query parameters" taking local dates and then converting them back to UTC. That way queries and data are both consistent around the globe.

Comment: @BlakesSeven But prob is that group by showing that record in previous date. is it possible to pass some parameters like date zone while making group by query on mongo ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dealing with timezones is a "client" issue, so you shoud be modifying "query" times by the timezone offset in order to allow "local" time selection in UI and so forth. The same goes for UI display where the dates are to be represented in the local time.

And the same applies to your arggregation principle. Just adjust by the timezone offset. Appply date math instead of using the date aggregation operators:

```js
var tzOffset = 2;

db.txs.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "$subtract": [
                { "$add": [ 
                    { "$subtract": [ "$date", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
                    tzOffset * 1000 * 60 * 60
                ]},
                { "$mod": [
                    { "$add": [ 
                        { "$subtract": [ "$date", new Date("1970-01-01") ] },
                        tzOffset * 1000 * 60 * 60
                    ]},
                    1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                ]}
            ]
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
]).forEach(function(doc){ 
    printjson({ "_id": new Date(doc._id), "count": doc.count }) 
});
```

Which gives you:

```js
{ "_id" : ISODate("2015-07-10T00:00:00Z"), "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2015-07-11T00:00:00Z"), "count" : 2 }
```

So when you [**`$subtract`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) one BSON date from another the result is the number of milliseconds since unix epoch. Simply then adjust this again by "adding" the "timezone offset" being either possitive for forward hours or negative for behind, again converted to valid millseconds from the time value.

The rounding then is a simple modulo [**`$mod`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/) to get the remainder from the "number of milliseconds in a day" and remove that to round out the adjusted date to the current day only.

The resulting numeric values here are easily re-cast back into dates since all language library "Date" objects take the milliseconds ( or seconds ) from epoch as a constructor argument.

So again, this is all about modifying the data response to present from the "locale" of your "client" and not about channging how the data is stored. If you want true locality in your application then you apply modifications for timezone offsets everywhere, just as is presented above.

--

Actually you can just create the date in the aggregation framework itself, with a little more date math. Simply add the epoch date back to the converted date:

```js
db.txs.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": { 
            "$add": [
                { "$subtract": [
                    { "$add": [ 
                        { "$subtract": [ "$date", new Date(0) ] },
                        tzOffset * 1000 * 60 * 60
                    ]},
                    { "$mod": [
                        { "$add": [ 
                            { "$subtract": [ "$date", new Date(0) ] },
                            tzOffset * 1000 * 60 * 60
                        ]},
                        1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
                    ]}
                ]},
                new Date(0);
            ]
        },
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Comment: @OmervanKloeten Sigh! You need to think about this harder and I am not saying to "discount DST" at all, but rather if that is a consideration for a date range on expected output then you "deal with it" by breaking up the adjustment from client locale data ( i.e these dates until DST break and these dates after ) for adjustment accordingly. Storing database content in GMT "just makes sense" since it is a stable point where you can make all adjustments from. That's the lesson here.

Answer (score 8):

in mongo version 3.6 timezone has been added, [mongo doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/index.html)

expression to extract date part with timezone is

```
{ date: <dateExpression>, timezone: <tzExpression> }
```

we can either specify the timezone or offset while getting the date parts

pipeline

```
> db.txs.aggregate([
...     { $group:{
...         _id: { 
...             day: {$dayOfMonth: {date :"$date", timezone : "Europe/Rome"}}, // timezone
...             month: {$month: {date : "$date", timezone : "+02:00"}}, //offset
...             year: {$year: {date : "$date", timezone : "+02:00"}} //offset
...         },
...         count:{$sum:1}
...     }}
... ])
```

result

```
{ "_id" : { "day" : 10, "month" : 7, "year" : 2015 }, "count" : 1 }
{ "_id" : { "day" : 11, "month" : 7, "year" : 2015 }, "count" : 2 }
>
```

list of [timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)