# Group by Date with Local Time Zone in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am new to mongodb. Below is my query.

```
Model.aggregate()
            .match({ 'activationId': activationId, "t": { "$gte": new Date(fromTime), "$lt": new Date(toTime) } })
            .group({ '_id': { 'date': { $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d %H", date: "$datefield" } } }, uniqueCount: { $addToSet: "$mac" } })
            .project({ "date": 1, "month": 1, "hour": 1, uniqueMacCount: { $size: "$uniqueCount" } })
            .exec()
            .then(function (docs) {
                return docs;
            });
```

The issue is mongodb stores date in iso timezone. I need this data for displaying area chart.

I want to group by date with local time zone. is there any way to add timeoffset into date when group by?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31353740/aggregating-in-local-timezone-in-mongodb.

Answer (score 20):

### General Problem of Dealing with "local dates"

So there is a short answer to this and a long answer as well. The basic case is that instead of using any of the ["date aggregation operators"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) you instead rather want to and "need to" actually "do the math" on the date objects instead. The primary thing here is to adjust the values by the offset from UTC for the given local timezone and then "round" to the required interval.

The "much longer answer" and also the main problem to consider involves that dates are often subject to "Daylight Savings Time" changes in the offset from UTC at different times of the year. So this means that when converting to "local time" for such aggregation purposes, you really should consider where the boundaries for such changes exist.

There is also another consideration, being that no matter what you do to "aggregate" at a given interval, the output values "should" at least initially come out as UTC. This is good practice since display to "locale" really is a "client function", and as later described, the client interfaces will commonly have a way of displaying in the present locale which will be based on the premise that it was in fact fed data as UTC.

### Determining Locale Offset and Daylight Savings

This is generally the main problem that needs to be solved. The general math for "rounding" a date to an interval is the simple part, but there is no real math you can apply to knowing when such boundaries apply, and the rules change in every locale and often every year.

So this is where a "library" comes in, and the best option here in the authors opinion for a JavaScript platform is [moment-timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/), which is basically a "superset" of [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) including all the important "timezeone" features we want to use.

Moment Timezone basically defines such a structure for each locale timezone as:

```
{
    name    : 'America/Los_Angeles',          // the unique identifier
    abbrs   : ['PDT', 'PST'],                 // the abbreviations
    untils  : [1414918800000, 1425808800000], // the timestamps in milliseconds
    offsets : [420, 480]                      // the offsets in minutes
}
```

Where of course the objects are ***much*** larger with respect to the `untils` and `offsets` properties actually recorded. But that is the data you need to access in order to see if there is actually a change in the offset for a zone given daylight savings changes.

This block of the later code listing is what we basically use to determine given a `start` and `end` value for a range, which daylight savings boundaries are crossed, if any:

```
  const zone = moment.tz.zone(locale);
  if ( zone.hasOwnProperty('untils') ) {
    let between = zone.untils.filter( u =>
      u >= start.valueOf() && u < end.valueOf()
    );
    if ( between.length > 0 )
      branches = between
        .map( d => moment.tz(d, locale) )
        .reduce((acc,curr,i,arr) =>
          acc.concat(
            ( i === 0 )
              ? [{ start, end: curr }] : [{ start: acc[i-1].end, end: curr }],
            ( i === arr.length-1 ) ? [{ start: curr, end }] : []
          )
        ,[]);
  }
```

Looking at the whole of 2017 for the `Australia/Sydney` locale the output of this would be:

```
[
  {
    "start": "2016-12-31T13:00:00.000Z",    // Interval is +11 hours here
    "end": "2017-04-01T16:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2017-04-01T16:00:00.000Z",    // Changes to +10 hours here
    "end": "2017-09-30T16:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2017-09-30T16:00:00.000Z",    // Changes back to +11 hours here
    "end": "2017-12-31T13:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

Which basically reveals that between the first sequence of dates the offset would be +11 hours then changes to +10 hours between the dates in the second sequence and then switches back to +11 hours for the interval covering to the end of the year and the specified range.

This logic then needs to be translated into a structure that will be understood by MongoDB as part of an aggregation pipeline.

### Applying the Math

The mathematical principle here for aggregating to any "rounded date interval" essentially relies on using the milliseconds value of the represented date which is "rounded" down to the nearest number representing the "interval" required.

You essentially do this by finding the "modulo" or "remainder" of the current value applied to the required interval. Then you "subtract" that remainder from the current value which returns a value at the nearest interval.

For example, given the current date:

```
  var d = new Date("2017-07-14T01:28:34.931Z"); // toValue() is 1499995714931 millis
  // 1000 millseconds * 60 seconds * 60 minutes = 1 hour or 3600000 millis
  var v = d.valueOf() - ( d.valueOf() % ( 1000 * 60 * 60 ) );
  // v equals 1499994000000 millis or as a date
  new Date(1499994000000);
  ISODate("2017-07-14T01:00:00Z") 
  // which removed the 28 minutes and change to nearest 1 hour interval
```

This is the general math we also need to apply in the aggregation pipeline using the [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) and [`$mod`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mod/) operations, which are the aggregation expressions used for the same math operations shown above.

The general structure of the aggregation pipeline is then:

```
    let pipeline = [
      { "$match": {
        "createdAt": { "$gte": start.toDate(), "$lt": end.toDate() }
      }},
      { "$group": {
        "_id": {
          "$add": [
            { "$subtract": [
              { "$subtract": [
                { "$subtract": [ "$createdAt", new Date(0) ] },
                switchOffset(start,end,"$createdAt",false)
              ]},
              { "$mod": [
                { "$subtract": [
                  { "$subtract": [ "$createdAt", new Date(0) ] },
                  switchOffset(start,end,"$createdAt",false)
                ]},
                interval
              ]}
            ]},
            new Date(0)
          ]
        },
        "amount": { "$sum": "$amount" }
      }},
      { "$addFields": {
        "_id": {
          "$add": [
            "$_id", switchOffset(start,end,"$_id",true)
          ]
        }
      }},
      { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
    ];
```

The main parts here you need to understand is the conversion from a `Date` object as stored in MongoDB to `Numeric` representing the internal timestamp value. We need the "numeric" form, and to do this is a trick of math where we subtract one BSON Date from another which yields the numeric difference between them. This is exactly what this statement does:

```
{ "$subtract": [ "$createdAt", new Date(0) ] }
```

Now we have a numeric value to deal with, we can apply the modulo and subtract that from the numeric representation of the date in order to "round" it. So the "straight" representation of this is like:

```
{ "$subtract": [
  { "$subtract": [ "$createdAt", new Date(0) ] },
  { "$mod": [
    { "$subtract": [ "$createdAt", new Date(0) ] },
    ( 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 ) // 24 hours
  ]}
]}
```

Which mirrors the same JavaScript math approach as shown earlier but applied to the actual document values in the aggregation pipeline. You will also note the other "trick" there where we apply an [`$add`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/add/) operation with another representation of a BSON date as of epoch ( or 0 milliseconds ) where the "addition" of a BSON Date to a "numeric" value, returns a "BSON Date" representing the milliseconds it was given as input.

Of course the other consideration in the listed code it the actual "offset" from UTC which is adjusting the numeric values in order to ensure the "rounding" takes place for the present timezone. This is implemented in a function based on the earlier description of finding where the different offsets occur, and returns a format as usable in an aggregation pipeline expression by comparing the input dates and returning the correct offset.

With the full expansion of all the details, including the generation of handling those different "Daylight Savings" time offsets would then be like:

```
[
  {
    "$match": {
      "createdAt": {
        "$gte": "2016-12-31T13:00:00.000Z",
        "$lt": "2017-12-31T13:00:00.000Z"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "$add": [
          {
            "$subtract": [
              {
                "$subtract": [
                  {
                    "$subtract": [
                      "$createdAt",
                      "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "$switch": {
                      "branches": [
                        {
                          "case": {
                            "$and": [
                              {
                                "$gte": [
                                  "$createdAt",
                                  "2016-12-31T13:00:00.000Z"
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "$lt": [
                                  "$createdAt",
                                  "2017-04-01T16:00:00.000Z"
                                ]
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          "then": -39600000
                        },
                        {
                          "case": {
                            "$and": [
                              {
                                "$gte": [
                                  "$createdAt",
                                  "2017-04-01T16:00:00.000Z"
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "$lt": [
                                  "$createdAt",
                                  "2017-09-30T16:00:00.000Z"
                                ]
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          "then": -36000000
                        },
                        {
                          "case": {
                            "$and": [
                              {
                                "$gte": [
                                  "$createdAt",
                                  "2017-09-30T16:00:00.000Z"
                                ]
                              },
                              {
                                "$lt": [
                                  "$createdAt",
                                  "2017-12-31T13:00:00.000Z"
                                ]
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                          "then": -39600000
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "$mod": [
                  {
                    "$subtract": [
                      {
                        "$subtract": [
                          "$createdAt",
                          "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "$switch": {
                          "branches": [
                            {
                              "case": {
                                "$and": [
                                  {
                                    "$gte": [
                                      "$createdAt",
                                      "2016-12-31T13:00:00.000Z"
                                    ]
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "$lt": [
                                      "$createdAt",
                                      "2017-04-01T16:00:00.000Z"
                                    ]
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              "then": -39600000
                            },
                            {
                              "case": {
                                "$and": [
                                  {
                                    "$gte": [
                                      "$createdAt",
                                      "2017-04-01T16:00:00.000Z"
                                    ]
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "$lt": [
                                      "$createdAt",
                                      "2017-09-30T16:00:00.000Z"
                                    ]
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              "then": -36000000
                            },
                            {
                              "case": {
                                "$and": [
                                  {
                                    "$gte": [
                                      "$createdAt",
                                      "2017-09-30T16:00:00.000Z"
                                    ]
                                  },
                                  {
                                    "$lt": [
                                      "$createdAt",
                                      "2017-12-31T13:00:00.000Z"
                                    ]
                                  }
                                ]
                              },
                              "then": -39600000
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  86400000
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
        ]
      },
      "amount": {
        "$sum": "$amount"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "_id": {
        "$add": [
          "$_id",
          {
            "$switch": {
              "branches": [
                {
                  "case": {
                    "$and": [
                      {
                        "$gte": [
                          "$_id",
                          "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "$lt": [
                          "$_id",
                          "2017-04-02T03:00:00.000Z"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": -39600000
                },
                {
                  "case": {
                    "$and": [
                      {
                        "$gte": [
                          "$_id",
                          "2017-04-02T02:00:00.000Z"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "$lt": [
                          "$_id",
                          "2017-10-01T02:00:00.000Z"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": -36000000
                },
                {
                  "case": {
                    "$and": [
                      {
                        "$gte": [
                          "$_id",
                          "2017-10-01T03:00:00.000Z"
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        "$lt": [
                          "$_id",
                          "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "then": -39600000
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "_id": 1
    }
  }
]
```

That expansion is using the [`$switch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) statement in order to apply the date ranges as conditions to when to return the given offset values. This is the most convenient form since the `"branches"` argument does correspond directly to an "array", which is the most convenient output of the "ranges" determined by examination of the `untils` representing the offset "cut-points" for the given timezone on the supplied date range of the query.

It is possible to apply the same logic in earlier versions of MongoDB using a "nested" implementation of [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) instead, but it is a little messier to implement, so we are just using the most convenient method in implementation here.

Once all of those conditions are applied, the dates "aggregated" are actually those representing the "local" time as defined by the supplied `locale`. This actually brings us to what the final aggregation stage is, and the reason why it is there as well as the later handling as demonstrated in the listing.

### End Results

I did mention earlier that the general recommendation is that the "output" should still return the date values in UTC format of at least some description, and therefore that is exactly what the pipeline here is doing by first converting "from" UTC to local by applying the offset when "rounding", but then the final numbers "after the grouping" are re-adjusted back by the same offset that applies to the "rounded" date values.

The listing here gives "three" different output possibilities here as:

```
// ISO Format string from JSON stringify default
[
  {
    "_id": "2016-12-31T13:00:00.000Z",
    "amount": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "2017-01-01T13:00:00.000Z",
    "amount": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "2017-01-02T13:00:00.000Z",
    "amount": 2
  }
]
// Timestamp value - milliseconds from epoch UTC - least space!
[
  {
    "_id": 1483189200000,
    "amount": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": 1483275600000,
    "amount": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": 1483362000000,
    "amount": 2
  }
]

// Force locale format to string via moment .format()
[
  {
    "_id": "2017-01-01T00:00:00+11:00",
    "amount": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "2017-01-02T00:00:00+11:00",
    "amount": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "2017-01-03T00:00:00+11:00",
    "amount": 2
  }
]
```

The one thing of note here is that for a "client" such as Angular, every single one of those formats would be accepted by it's own [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe) which can actually do the "locale format" for you. But it depends on where the data is supplied to. "Good" libraries will be aware of using a UTC date in the present locale. Where that is not the case, then you might need to "stringify" yourself.

But it is a simple thing, and you get the most support for this by using a library which essentially bases it's manipulation of output from a "given UTC value".

The main thing here is to "understand what you are doing" when you ask such a thing as aggregating to a local time zone. Such a process should consider:

1. The data can be and often is viewed from the perspective of people within different timezones.
2. The data is generally provided by people in different timezones. Combined with point 1, this is why we store in UTC.
3. Timezones are often subject to a changing "offset" from "Daylight Savings Time" in many of the world timezones, and you should account for that when analyzing and processing the data.
4. Regardless of aggregation intervals, output "should" in fact remain in UTC, albeit adjusted to aggregate on interval according to the locale provided. This leaves presentation to be delegated to a "client" function, just as it should.

As long as you keep those things in mind and apply just like the listing here demonstrates, then you are doing all the right things for dealing with aggregation of dates and even general storage with respect to a given locale.

So you "should" be doing this, and what you "should not" be doing is giving up and simply storing the "locale date" as a string. As described, that would be a very incorrect approach and causes nothing but further problems for your application.

> **NOTE**: The one topic I do not touch on here at all is aggregating to a "month" *( or indeed "year" )* interval. "Months" are the mathematical anomaly in the whole process since the number of days always varies and thus requires a whole other set of logic in order to apply. Describing that alone is at least as long as this post, and therefore would be another subject. For general minutes, hours, and days which is the common case, the math here is "good enough" for those cases.

---

### Full Listing

This serves as a "demonstration" to tinker with. It employs the required function to extract the offset dates and values to be included and runs an aggregation pipeline over the supplied data.

You can change anything in here, but will probably start with the `locale` and `interval` parameters, and then maybe add different data and different `start` and `end` dates for the query. But the rest of the code need not be changed to simply make changes to any of those values, and can therefore demonstrate using different intervals ( such as `1 hour` as asked in the question ) and different locales.

For instance, once supplying valid data which would actually require aggregation at a "1 hour interval" then the line in the listing would be changed as:

```
const interval = moment.duration(1,'hour').asMilliseconds();
```

In order to define a milliseconds value for the aggregation interval as required by the aggregation operations being performed on the dates.

---

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone'),
      mongoose = require('mongoose'),
      Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.set('debug',true);

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost/test',
      options = { useMongoClient: true };

const locale = 'Australia/Sydney';
const interval = moment.duration(1,'day').asMilliseconds();

const reportSchema = new Schema({
  createdAt: Date,
  amount: Number
});

const Report = mongoose.model('Report', reportSchema);

function log(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2))
}

function switchOffset(start,end,field,reverseOffset) {

  let branches = [{ start, end }]

  const zone = moment.tz.zone(locale);
  if ( zone.hasOwnProperty('untils') ) {
    let between = zone.untils.filter( u =>
      u >= start.valueOf() && u < end.valueOf()
    );
    if ( between.length > 0 )
      branches = between
        .map( d => moment.tz(d, locale) )
        .reduce((acc,curr,i,arr) =>
          acc.concat(
            ( i === 0 )
              ? [{ start, end: curr }] : [{ start: acc[i-1].end, end: curr }],
            ( i === arr.length-1 ) ? [{ start: curr, end }] : []
          )
        ,[]);
  }

  log(branches);

  branches = branches.map( d => ({
    case: {
      $and: [
        { $gte: [
          field,
          new Date(
            d.start.valueOf()
            + ((reverseOffset)
              ? moment.duration(d.start.utcOffset(),'minutes').asMilliseconds()
              : 0)
          )
        ]},
        { $lt: [
          field,
          new Date(
            d.end.valueOf()
            + ((reverseOffset)
              ? moment.duration(d.start.utcOffset(),'minutes').asMilliseconds()
              : 0)
          )
        ]}
      ]
    },
    then: -1 * moment.duration(d.start.utcOffset(),'minutes').asMilliseconds()
  }));

  return ({ $switch: { branches } });

}

(async function() {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri,options);

    // Data cleanup
    await Promise.all(
      Object.keys(conn.models).map( m => conn.models[m].remove({}))
    );

    let inserted = await Report.insertMany([
      { createdAt: moment.tz("2017-01-01",locale), amount: 1 },
      { createdAt: moment.tz("2017-01-01",locale), amount: 1 },
      { createdAt: moment.tz("2017-01-02",locale), amount: 1 },
      { createdAt: moment.tz("2017-01-03",locale), amount: 1 },
      { createdAt: moment.tz("2017-01-03",locale), amount: 1 },
    ]);

    log(inserted);

    const start = moment.tz("2017-01-01", locale)
          end   = moment.tz("2018-01-01", locale)

    let pipeline = [
      { "$match": {
        "createdAt": { "$gte": start.toDate(), "$lt": end.toDate() }
      }},
      { "$group": {
        "_id": {
          "$add": [
            { "$subtract": [
              { "$subtract": [
                { "$subtract": [ "$createdAt", new Date(0) ] },
                switchOffset(start,end,"$createdAt",false)
              ]},
              { "$mod": [
                { "$subtract": [
                  { "$subtract": [ "$createdAt", new Date(0) ] },
                  switchOffset(start,end,"$createdAt",false)
                ]},
                interval
              ]}
            ]},
            new Date(0)
          ]
        },
        "amount": { "$sum": "$amount" }
      }},
      { "$addFields": {
        "_id": {
          "$add": [
            "$_id", switchOffset(start,end,"$_id",true)
          ]
        }
      }},
      { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }
    ];

    log(pipeline);
    let results = await Report.aggregate(pipeline);

    // log raw Date objects, will stringify as UTC in JSON
    log(results);

    // I like to output timestamp values and let the client format
    results = results.map( d =>
      Object.assign(d, { _id: d._id.valueOf() })
    );
    log(results);

    // Or use moment to format the output for locale as a string
    results = results.map( d =>
      Object.assign(d, { _id: moment.tz(d._id, locale).format() } )
    );
    log(results);

  } catch(e) {
    console.error(e);
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
})()
```

Answer (score 5):

November 2017 saw the release of MongoDB v3.6, which included timezone-aware date aggregation operators. I would encourage anyone reading this to put them to use rather than rely on client-side date manipulation, as demonstrated in Neil's answer, particularly because it is way easier to read and understand.

Depending on the requirements, different operators might come in handy, but I've found `$dateToParts` to be the most universal/generic. Here's a basic demonstration using OP's example:

```
project({
  dateParts: {
    // This will split the date stored in `dateField` into parts
    $dateToParts: {
      date: "$dateField",
      // This can be an Olson timezone, such as Europe/London, or
      // a fixed offset, such as +0530 for India.
      timezone: "+05:30"
    }
  }
})
.group({
  _id: {
    // Here we group by hour! Using these date parts grouping
    // by hour/day/month/etc. is trivial - start with the year
    // and add every unit greater than or equal to the target
    // unit.
    year: "$dateParts.year",
    month: "$dateParts.month",
    day: "$dateParts.day",
    hour: "$dateParts.hour"
  },
  uniqueCount: {
    $addToSet: "$mac"
  }
})
.project({
  _id: 0,
  year: "$_id.year",
  month: "$_id.month",
  day: "$_id.day",
  hour: "$_id.hour",
  uniqueMacCount: { $size: "$uniqueCount" }
});
```

Alternatively, one might wish to assemble the date parts back to a date object. This is also very simple with the inverse `$dateFromParts` operator:

```
project({
  _id: 0,
  date: {
    $dateFromParts: {
      year: "$_id.year",
      month: "$_id.month",
      day: "$_id.day",
      hour: "$_id.hour",
      timezone: "+05:30"
    }
  },
  uniqueMacCount: { $size: "$uniqueCount" }
})
```

The great thing here is that all the underlying dates remain in UTC and any returned dates are also in UTC.

Unfortunately, it seems that grouping by more unusual arbitrary ranges, such as half-day, might be harder. I haven't given it much thought however.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will help someone coming to this question.

There is property "timezone" in $dateToString object.

For example:

```
$dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d %H", date: "$datefield", timezone: "Europe/London" }
```