# How to include timezone in $week mongo aggregation with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently trying to group a set of documents by the week number of an exit_time field.

I can do so fine with the $week aggregation like so.

```
$group: {
  _id: {$week: "$exit_time"}
}
```

However if I try to include the timezone like in the mongodb documentation I get the following error.

```
MongoError: can't convert from BSON type object to Date
```

Here's the code snippet that's causing it. As far as I can tell it is how the examples do it in the mongo documentation.

```
$group: {
  _id: {
    $week: {
      date: "$exit_time",
      timezone: "America/Tijuana"
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the relevant documentation.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/week/

Has anyone ran into a similar issue that can point me in the right direction?

Comment: The error might be a bit misleading, but clearly you don't actually have **MongoDB 3.6**, just like the statement ( *changed in MongoDB 3.6* ) actually says in the documentation before it talks about the addition of timezone conversion. If you don't have MongoDB 3.6 you need to take a mathematical approach to adjusting timezones

Comment: Gory details at [Group by Date with Local Time Zone in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45038711/2313887) and of course generally superseded by the `timezone` option in date operators  since MongoDB 3.6, but covers adjustments including shifts in DST to be applied for earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

As Neil Lunn said, the issue for me was that I was actually running a pre 3.6 version of MongoDB (although I thought I was running 3.6).